# WatchKit SF monospaced number

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, xcode7

Is there any way to set monospaced for San Francisco font in WatchKit? In Introducing the New System Fonts, the presenter only shows for AppKit.

Sample code is appreciated.

Xcode: 7.0 beta
WatchOS: 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample code:

```
UIFont *systemFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];  
UIFontDescriptor *monospacedNumberFontDescriptor = [systemFont.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes: @{  
     UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: @[@{  
          UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @6,  
          UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @0  
     }]  
}];  

UIFont *monospacedNumberSystemFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:monospacedNumberFontDescriptor size:0];  
NSMutableAttributedString *monospacedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"1234567890"];  
[monospacedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:monospacedNumberSystemFont range:NSMakeRange(0, monospacedString.string.length)];  

[label setAttributedText:monospacedString];
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift version:

```
let monospacedFont = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(16, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
let monospacedString = NSAttributedString(string: "1234", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: monospacedFont])
textLabel.setAttributedText(monospacedString)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

```
extension WKInterfaceLabel {
    func setMonospacedText(_ text: String) {
        let monospacedFont = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: monospacedFont])
        self.setAttributedText(attributedString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SF Compact` for Apple Watch..

> Apple Watch uses two variants of the San Francisco Compact: Display
>   and Text. These fonts were designed specifically for legibility on
>   small screens.

For more info, refer `Typeface` section of this [link.](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/resources/)